# Django admin table functionality in templates

Tags: django, django-admin

Django has a nice sortable table system in the admin. I would like to know how can I use that in my regular templates.

I couldn´t find any info about this. Any clues welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use javascript free control with pagination, sortable , search functions.

Comment: https://datatables.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js "> </script>



   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>






   <script>

   $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable();
      } );

   </script> 


</head>
<body>



<table id="example" class="display"  >
  <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>name</th>
          <th>position</th>
          <th>office</th>
          <th>age</th>
          <th> date </th>

      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      {% for i in qs %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ i.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ i.position }}</td>
        <td>{{ i.office }}</td>
        <td>{{ i.age }}</td>
        <td> {{ i.date }} </td> 
      </tr>
    {% endfor %} 
    </tbody>
  </table>


</body>
</html>
```

[image]